# magento xml order returning - failed to parse submitted XML

Tags: php, xml, magento, xslt, curl

I'm at a brick wall. My first ever post here on stackoverflow, though I use it for solving other problems all the time. This time I can't find an exsisitng solution that solves my problem.

I'm trying to setup xml dropship/ordering from a supplier. But no matter what I do I keep getting the below reture value. The jobs for a friend, so I've no budjet to hire anyone to help me (clever of me to take it on right?)

```
Destination "nameofcompany API" (ID: 1): API returned: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE XGResponse SYSTEM "http://intcom.xml.quality.nameofcompany.de:8080/XMLGate/XMLGateResponse.dtd"> <XGResponse><Failure code="400"> Failed to parse submitted XML Document.org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog. </Failure></XGResponse>
```

I've tested the xml that gets ouputted, and it all validates fine, I even have that confirmed by the IT department of that company, who conveniantly don't know what's going wrong and have no logs of requests sent to them.

The xsl template is setup as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
<file filename="export_%lastincrementid%.xml"><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="php">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
<![CDATA[!DOCTYPE OrderEnv SYSTEM "http://integratex.quality.nameofcompany.de:8080/ix/dtd/ixOrder4.dtd"]]>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
<!--<!DOCTYPE OrderEnv SYSTEM "http://integratex.nameofcompany.com:8080/ix/dtd/ixOrder4.dtd"> Live-->
<OrderEnv AuthCode="code-goes-here">
<xsl:attribute name="MsgID"><xsl:value-of select="$exportid"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
<Order>
<xsl:attribute name="Currency"><xsl:value-of select="order_currency_code"/></xsl:attribute>
<Head>
<Title><xsl:value-of select="increment_id"/></Title>
<OrderDate><xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('strftime', '%Y%m%d', created_at_timestamp)"/></OrderDate>
<!--<DelDate></DelDate>--> 
<CustContact></CustContact> 
<!-- <ThirdParty>
<Address> 
<Name1>string</Name1>
<Name2>string</Name2>
<Name3>string</Name3>
<Name4>string</Name4> 
<Street>string</Street> 
<ZIP>string</ZIP> 
<City>string</City> 
<District>string</District> 
<Country>str</Country> 
<ContactName>string</ContactName> 
<ContactPhone>string</ContactPhone> 
<ContactMail>string</ContactMail> 
</Address> </ThirdParty> 
<Reseller> 
<ContactName>string</ContactName> 
<ContactPhone>string</ContactPhone> 
<ContactMail>string</ContactMail> 
</Reseller> --> 
<DeliverTo> 
<Address> 
<Name1><xsl:value-of select="concat(shipping/firstname, ' ', shipping/lastname)"/></Name1>
<Name2><xsl:value-of select="shipping/company"/></Name2>
<Name3></Name3>
<Name4></Name4>
<Street><xsl:value-of select="concat(shipping/street1, ' ', shipping/street2)"/></Street>
<ZIP><xsl:value-of select="shipping/postcode"/></ZIP>
<City><xsl:value-of select="shipping/city"/></City>
<District><xsl:value-of select="shipping/region"/></District>
<Country><xsl:value-of select="shipping/country_id"/></Country>
<!--<DeliveryNoteLanguage></DeliveryNoteLanguage>-->
<ContactName><xsl:value-of select="concat(shipping/firstname, ' ', shipping/lastname)"/></ContactName> <ContactPhone><xsl:value-of select="shipping/telephone"/></ContactPhone>
<ContactMail><xsl:value-of select="customer_email"/></ContactMail>
</Address></DeliverTo>
<Delivery Type="" Condition="y" Full="y" POD="n"/>
<OrigPO><xsl:value-of select="increment_id"/></OrigPO>
<FreeTxt Type="info"></FreeTxt>
<ShipTxt></ShipTxt>
<InvoicTxt></InvoicTxt>
<CODamount><xsl:if test="payment/method='cashondelivery'"><xsl:value-of select="grand_total"/></xsl:if></CODamount>
</Head>
<Body>
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">
<Line>
<xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
<ItemID><xsl:value-of select="sku"/></ItemID>
<Qty><xsl:value-of select="round(qty)"/></Qty>
<Price><xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('number_format', price, 2, '.', '')"/></Price>
<ConfigID></ConfigID>
<AgreementNumber></AgreementNumber>
<BundleID></BundleID>
<EndUserID></EndUserID>
<OrigPO></OrigPO>
<FreeTxt Type="info"></FreeTxt>
<ShipTxt></ShipTxt>
<UsageCode></UsageCode>
<LineType></LineType>
<ConfigNo></ConfigNo>
</Line></xsl:for-each>
</Body>
</Order>
</xsl:for-each>
</OrderEnv>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</file>
</files>
```

and it ouputs the following xml message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE OrderEnv SYSTEM "http://integratex.quality.nameofcompany.de:8080/ix/dtd/ixOrder4.dtd"><OrderEnv AuthCode="the-auth-code" MsgID="21">
  <Order Currency="GBP">
    <Head>
      <Title>100000006</Title>
      <OrderDate>20140117</OrderDate>
      <CustContact/>
      <DeliverTo>
        <Address>
          <Name1>Nate</Name1>
          <Name2></Name2>
          <Name3/>
          <Name4/>
          <Street>638 Moave street </Street>
          <ZIP>NE34567</ZIP>
          <City>Fakeville</City>
          <District></District>
          <Country>GB</Country>
          <ContactName>Nate</ContactName>
          <ContactPhone>00098989890</ContactPhone>
          <ContactMail>myemail@email.com</ContactMail>
        </Address>
      </DeliverTo>
      <Delivery Type="" Condition="y" Full="y" POD="n"/>
      <OrigPO>100000006</OrigPO>
      <FreeTxt Type="info"/>
      <ShipTxt/>
      <InvoicTxt/>
      <CODamount>105.0000</CODamount>
    </Head>
    <Body>
      <Line ID="1">
        <ItemID>1497866</ItemID>
        <Qty>1</Qty>
        <Price>100.00</Price>
        <ConfigID/>
        <AgreementNumber/>
        <BundleID/>
        <EndUserID/>
        <OrigPO/>
        <FreeTxt Type="info"/>
        <ShipTxt/>
        <UsageCode/>
        <LineType/>
        <ConfigNo/>
      </Line>
    </Body>
  </Order>
</OrderEnv>
```

And below is the http post method (if that's the right way of reffering to it)

```
    public function nameofcompany($fileArray)

    {

        // Do whatever - sample code for a HTTP request below.

        foreach ($fileArray as $filename => $fileContent) {

            $curlClient = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://intcom.xml.quality.nameofcompany.de:8080/XMLGate/inbound'); //Prod: http://intcom.xml.nameofcompany-europe.com:8080/XMLGate/inbound

            curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xmlmsg' => $fileContent));

            #curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

            #curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

            $result = curl_exec($curlClient);

$logEntry = Mage::registry('export_log');
$logEntry->addResultMessage(Mage::helper('xtento_orderexport')->__('Destination "%s" (ID: %s): %s', $this->getDestination()->getName(), $this->getDestination()->getId(), 'API returned: '.htmlentities($result)));

            curl_close($curlClient);

        }

    }
```

To my mind there's something getting thrown into the message when it's being sent, and it's not showing in the xml file log that's getting stored locally on the server, that I showed you above. I even checked the xml file in a hex editor and couldn't find any hint of a DOM or anything else that's being snuck in before the message starts.

NB: I'm quite new to PHP/XML, so if I'm not specific enough anywhere here, or am using the wrong terminology, do forgive me. I'm trying to work most of this out as I go. And if you want me to provide any more details, just say the word.

Cheers
Nate

Comment: Any sucess with this issue? I just ran into same problem today.

Comment: @NenadBulatovic I did get it working in the end. It worked after the following content type header was sent.

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

If I can do anything else, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, have you checked the XML for BOM (byte order mark)?

Comment: thanks for the reply mate. I ran the messages (that are saved locally on the server after the file is sent) through a hex editor, and couldn't see a blessed thing. I'm not sure how to test sending the file direct to myself using the same protocol I would in sending it to the supplier. So all I've been able to do is check the local xml files, which have no errors at all, but I'm guessing they're not including everything that's being sent.

Comment: Same happened to me - when I save it locally on disk and try to parse it - everything went OK, but when I try to parse remotely error occurs.